# Is lesbianism prohibited for gentiles

Tags: halacha, sexuality, noachide-laws, homosexuality, even-haezer

According to Halacha, Jews are prohibited from gay female (lesbian) relationships. My question is, does this prohibition apply to Bnei Noach, or merely the prohibition against male homosexual relationships?